# elastic search, is it possible to update nested objects without updating the entire document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm indexing a set of documents (imagine them as forum posts) with a nested object which is the user related to that post. My problem is that the user fields might be updated, but since the posts do not change they are not reindexed and the user nested objects become outdated. Is there a way to update the nested objects without reindexing the whole document again? Or the only solution would be to reindex all the related posts of a user everytime that the user changes?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the Update API.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/docs/posts/post/_update -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.nested_user = updated_nested_user",
    "params" : {
        "updated_nested_user" : {"field": "updated"}
    }
}'
```

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722197/updating-indexed-document-in-elasticsearch) for full detail.

Note that update scripts support conditional logic, as shown [here](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html). So you could tag forum posts when the user changes, then iterate over the posts to update only posts with changed users.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/docs/posts/post/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.tags.contains(tag) ? "ctx._source.nested_user = updated_nested_John" : ctx.op = "none"",
    "params" : {
        "tag": "updated_John_tag",
        "updated_nested_John" : {"field": "updated"}
    }
}'
```

*UPDATED*

Perhaps my ternary operator example was incomplete. This was not mentioned in the question, but assuming that users change their info in a separate part of the app, it would be nice to apply those changes to the forum posts in one script. Instead of using tags, try checking the user field directly for changes:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/docs/posts/post/_update' -d '{
    "script" : "ctx._source.nested_user.contains(user) ? "ctx._source.nested_user = updated_nested_John" : ctx.op = "none"",
    "params" : {
        "user": "John",
        "updated_nested_John" : {"field": "updated"}
    }
}'
```

As mentioned, though, this may be a slower operation than reindexing the full posts.

Comment: 2 things: `+=` will append the new user to a (now growing) array of nested users. Also, why would you go through all posts tagging them to be updated, then updating them in a second pass?

Comment: @ScottRice How does Elasticsearch know which nested object to replace? In other words, in the above example, how does Elasticsearch know you want to replace the current John object (as opposed to say, the "Sally" object)? Is there some key for each nested document?

Comment: hi, i iterate over the nested documents using a loop for (int i = 0; i < ctx._source.nested_user.size(); i++) , is this how you solved it?

Comment: The comment by @PeteyPabPro doesn't seem to have been addressed, yet. I would also be curious to know how to update a specific nested doc. In the example above, which field does `"user": "John"`pertain to and how would ES "know" that it is used as an ID for the nested doc here?

Answer (score 12):

Sadly elasticsearch cannot update only part of a document without reindexing the whole document. So, yes you would need to reindex the whole document to change a nested part.

If you don't have the whole document to hand to resend it, you can just send the part that needs changing using the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/docs-update.html), but be warned there are performance issues.

Comment: That is not true. Elasticsearch is very capable of updating parts of documents, and that too on the basis of conditions as well. Look at *upsert* in http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html.

Comment: If you read the question @vaidik you will see he is asking about updating a nested doc without re-indexing. Unless elasticsearch has changed recently, you cannot only re-index part of the document. I also link to the update API. From the docs themselves: "Note, this operation still means full reindex of the document, it just removes some network roundtrips and reduces chances of version conflicts between the get and the index. The _source field need to be enabled for this feature to work."

Comment: I will edit the language of my answer as I see how it could be misinterpreted.

Comment: @ramseykhalaf I couldn't confirm your claims about the whole document reindexing with nested documents on the Update API link. But when you go to Parent-child it is confirmed: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html

Answer (score 5):

Answer by @Scott Rice on how to use partial update in this context is very useful, while answer by @ramseykhalaf is more correct in sense that this is not possible without reindexing. If we do partial update, we do reindexing whole document anyway.

However depends on understanding of what "reindexing" is.

If we define reindexing as "resubmitting whole document to ES" - then we can call partial update the solution without reindexing in this sense.
If we define reindexing as "recalculating data structures allowing to efficiently search for updated document in index" (which is more correct definition to my understanding), then it always happen.

Please note that whole old copy of document will remain in index after partial update, marked as deleted (until next complete reindex from scratch or "optimize").

To avoid this, child-parent relationship can be used instead of nested objects. Children can be added/deleted/updated without touching the parent document (however this have its cost of course - maintaining child-parent relationship forest in memory etc.).