# elasticsearch: update in a nested object (HTTP)

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I'm trying to update a partial nested object with a script. But what I have written is incorrect.

I've this object:

```
{
  "_index" : "test_7",
  "_type" : "testField",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "view" : {
      "hit" : 3,
      "pages" : [
        {
          "name" : "A",
          "hit" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "B",
          "hit" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "C",
          "hit" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like add 3 hits on a page.

With the existing page named "B":

```
  {
    "view" : {
      "hit" : 6,
      "pages" : [
        {
          "name" : "A",
          "hit" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "B",
          "hit" : 4
        },
        {
          "name" : "C",
          "hit" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

With a new page named "D":

```
  {
    "view" : {
      "hit" : 6,
      "pages" : [
        {
          "name" : "A",
          "hit" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "B",
          "hit" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "C",
          "hit" : 1
        },
        {
          "name" : "D",
          "hit" : 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Please can you tell me how write the HTTP request? 
Moreover where can I read more documentation about "ctx._source"?

Thanks.

Comment: "I would like add 3 hits if the P page." - Your question is not very clear. Are you talking about two different scenarios ?

Comment: Yes because I don't know how many pages has my object. I may update an existing page, or I may add a new page.

I looked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360225/elastic-search-is-it-possible-to-update-nested-objects-without-updating-the-ent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctx_source is nothing but the source JSON document that you submitted for indexing for that particular document. 
You need to use scripting support in the [_update API](http://blog.qbox.io/introduction-to-elasticsearch-scripting)

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/data/data/X_UucUuYTOqdB8eo2H-XWw/_update' -d '{
  "script": "increment",
  "params": {
    "newPage": {
      "name": "A",
      "hit": 40
    }
  }
}'
```

Increment script

```
source = ctx._source
Boolean isAdded = false;
for(page in source.view.pages){
    if(page.name == newPage.name){
        page.hit += newPage.hit
        isAdded = true
    }
}
if(!isAdded){
    source.view.pages += newPage
}
```

Here , specify the count and the pageName in the params section. If the pageName is something that is existing , that value would be incremented or a new one would be appended.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thx! 

Meanwhile I read mvel documentation (ES < 1.4): 
http://mvel.codehaus.org/Language+Guide+for+2.0

And I wrote an ugly script. Your one is better.
Just for remaining:
    
    {
        "script" : "if ((name in ctx._source.view.pages).contains(updated_data.name)) { current = ($ in ctx._source.view.pages if $.name == updated_data.name)[0]; current.hit += updated_data.hit; } else { ctx._source.view.pages += updated_data; } ",
        "params" : {
            "updated_data" : {
                "name": "ini1",
                "hit": 3
            }
        }
    }