# how to incrementally update nested objects in elasticsearch?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have 2 document types (in normal form in relational db):

1: post (with title, text and author fields)

2: comment (with text, author, post_id fields)

I have only one type in elastic (post) that aggregate each post with all comments on them in nested form.

I want to index posts with comments on it as nested objects for decreasing response time of queries but it will increase cost of indexing significantly if I reindex whole "post" document every time a new "comment" added, how can I handle it efficiently? It is acceptable for me to have data of comments with 1h delay.

In fact it is three question:

**1- how can I update a post document with only added comment data. (without need to reconstruct whole post document and send it to elastic)**

**2- how can I aggregate index commands that was related to a document and send it as a one single command to elastic?**

**3- Is river plugin a solution for these? is it index comments without need to reconstruct whole post document? is it aggregate all updates related to one document and apply it with one index request?**

Answer (score 0):

I think this post answers your questions:
[elastic search, is it possible to update nested objects without updating the entire document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360225/elastic-search-is-it-possible-to-update-nested-objects-without-updating-the-ent)

Having multiple items to update can be done using the bulk api

There is no river that can help you not to reindex the whole document. With nested documents you always reindex the complete document. If this happens a lot and becomes a problem, parent-child mappings are the way to go.

Comment: I find how to apply update patch index but I still have some concerns about multiple update on a single document, I want to know do river plugin or bulk operation aggregate multiple updates on a single documnet in one single update command or it just run them sequentially and myself should aggregate these index commands and send them as a bulk operation?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to accomplish with the river? Are you trying to find a solution to the problem if multiple updates to the same document are tried? You could use the version attribute for that. Check this url: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/optimistic-concurrency-control.html