# ElasticSearch update with scripts : what does ctx mean?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1/_update?pretty' -d '
{
  "script" : "ctx._source.age += 5"
}'
```

This an example on official site. I am confused with ctx, what does it mean? Context?

Comment: 'context'. It refers to all the data you are scoping.

Comment: Have a look at this one, it looks like the answer to what you're looking for...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722197/updating-indexed-document-in-elasticsearch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating indexed document in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722197/updating-indexed-document-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ctx` is a special variable that allows you to access the source of the object that you want to update. The `ctx._source` is a writable version of the `source`.

**NOTE:** You can modify this document in the script and the modified source will be persisted as the new version of the document.

Comment: I want to send error log messages to slack, so how to add error logs in message content eg: Monitor {{ctx.monitor.name}} just entered alert status. Please investigate the issue.
- Trigger: {{ctx.trigger.name}}
- Severity: {{ctx.trigger.severity}}
- Period start: {{ctx.periodStart}}
- Period end: {{ctx.periodEnd}}

Error :

Comment: pls check this link for od alerting module. I hope you got this answer earlier.

https://discuss.opendistrocommunity.dev/t/kibana-email-alert-extracting-field-results/3606/34

I am checking for math operations in od alerting. 

{{ ctx.results.0.hits.total.value / ctx.results.0.aggregations.when.sum_other_doc_count }}